Material-React-Table in Edit Upload Button Returning same Value for all the columns

  const table = useMaterialReactTable({
    columns,
    data: row,
    enablePagination: true,
    enableBottomToolbar: true,
    enableColumnFilterModes: true,
    enableColumnOrdering: true,
    enableGrouping: true,
    enableColumnPinning: true,
    enableFacetedValues: true,
    enableRowActions: true,
    enableFullScreenToggle: true,

    initialState: {
        positionActionsColumn: 'first',
        showGlobalFilter: true,
        pagination: { pageSize: 10 },
        density: 'compact',
        columnPinning: {
            left: ['mrt-row-actions'],
        },
    },
    getRowId: (row) => row.id,
    renderRowActions: ({ row, table }) => (
        <div> <label htmlFor="files" className="btn"><CIcon icon={cilCloudUpload} /></label>
            <input id="files" type="file" style={{ visibility: "hidden" }} className='form-control' onChange={() => {uploadImage(row); setRow(row)}} />
        </div>
    ),

});


    const uploadImage = async (event, CellValue) => {
       
        let fileObj = event.target.files[0];
       

    }

In this code File Upload has a value row always returning same value as a First row . Even when i click second row it's returning first row value
In this code File Upload has a value row always returning same value as a First row . Even when i click second row it's returning first row value
